# Detecting if a Number is within a Certain Range

Tags: java, random, probability

I have a portion of code which generates a random number, and then attempts to find out where the number falls, between zero and some probability, stored in an array as a percentage. I understand that this may sound much more confusing than it actually is, so here is my code, essentially, in Java:

```
Random rand = new Random();
double currentProbability = rand.nextDouble();

// these are the "percentages" I refer to above
// note that they will not necessarily be in least-to-greatest/greatest-to-least 
// order
double[] probabilities = new double[]{0.49, 0.49, 0.02};
// the objects in the array below correspond to the probabilities at the same 
// index in the "probabilities" array above
Object[] correspondingObjects = new Object[]{new Object(), new Object(), new Object()};

// here, I would find between which percentage the random number lies, and choose
// the corresponding object from the array of Objects
```

Therefore, my issue is mainly how to select in which index the random number lies, if the probability is given as a percentage. Perhaps I am over-complicating this, and I would ask that any user who believes that this is the case leave a comment below instead of down-voting this question.

Comment: whats the range of numbers over which you want to find the distribution ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that's quite important: the values in the probability array will always sum to 100%; however, there may be as few as two probabilities in this array, with the remaining value having been set to `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D.E. Knuth describes a method that is beneficial if the number of cases to choose from is large. If you have to choose among n cases, you distribute them into n-1 buckets of equal sizes, such that there are no more than 2 cases in each bucket. It can be shown that this is always possible. To select a case is then a two step process that can be performed in constant time: first select a bucket, then decide which of the two cases in this bucket applies.

For example if the distribution for A, B, C is [0.49, 0.49, 0.02] we would come up with two buckets of size 0.5 each. The first contains 0.02 C and 0.48 A; the second 0.01 A and 0.49 B. In sum, you get the original probabilities.

If the generated random number r is below 0.5 we choose the first bucket, if r is below 0.02 the case C is selected, otherwise A. If r is above 0.5, the second bucket is selected and if (r-0.5) is below 0.01 we select case A otherwise case B.

Comment: If you are referring to user1257931's answer, you have definitely shed some new light on it for me. I believe that I will mark his answer as correct (and upvote yours) if this is the case.

Comment: It is not related to user1257931's answer, it also works if you have very fine precision. For each bucket you just have to store one real number (the border between the two cases), and which cases are in the bucket.

Comment: Yes, I see the distinction now. Well then, an up-vote and a green check are on their way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for finding index:

```
    int index = 0;
    while (true) {
        currentProbability -= probabilities[index];
        if (currentProbability <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: why not sort the probabilities first, to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a weighted shuffle.  depending on the size of your set, it may be easier to just load a List with objects multiple times then use the static shuffle(List) method in java.util.Collection and pop an object off the top of the List.

For instance,
  for [.49,.49,.02] this would be normalized.

for [.10, .10, .80] this would normalize to [.1, .1, .8] so if this is [A, B, C] you would load 1 A, 1 B and 8 C objects into a list then use shuffle.

Obviously, if you have a very fine precision on your List and lots of objects then this solution would not be optimal.

Comment: I cannot make assumptions due to the nature of my situation, so I must consider the possibility of a very fine precision, unfortunately. Nonetheless, this is worthy of an up-vote